# Could not view Forge viewer model on mobile browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am not able to view forge viewer model on my tablet (IPAD or Android) despite that I have no problem on my Iphone. I am trying to open it in web application by using google chrome or safari and it is failed. What can be the problem?

When I try another viewer as in below link, it does not work, too.
https://autodesk-forge.github.io/forge-tutorial-postman/display_svf.html

Comment: can you try a site like viewer-rocks.autodesk.io and see if that works? if not I would check if you have JS enabled on your device.

Comment: I tried above link(viewer-rocks.autodesk.io) and it works. what can be the problem for my case?